# How to read RS485 output from my wind direction sensor with Controllino Maxi

Tags: arduino, modbus, rs485

I need outputs in degree to read in Arduino IDE

Products:
Wind direction sensor (SEN0482) and Controllino Maxi.

[image: Wiring]

I have attempted to get any form of output from my wind direction sensor using a different code, but the only thing I could get was "Fail 226". This suggests that there might be an issue either with the connections or with the code that reads the sensor.

Here is my code:

```
#include <Controllino.h>
#include "ModbusMaster.h"

// Definer pins for RE og DE kontrol af RS485
const int rs485_re = 68; // Receiver Enable
const int rs485_de = 69; // Driver Enable

// Opret en instans af ModbusMaster klasse
ModbusMaster modbus;

void preTransmission() {
  digitalWrite(rs485_re, LOW);
  digitalWrite(rs485_de, HIGH);
}

void postTransmission() {
  digitalWrite(rs485_re, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(rs485_de, LOW);
}

void setup() {
  // Initialiser pins for RS485 kontrol
  pinMode(rs485_re, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rs485_de, OUTPUT);

  // Sæt RE og DE til inaktiv tilstand (RE=HIGH, DE=LOW)
  digitalWrite(rs485_re, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(rs485_de, LOW);

  // Start RS485 kommunikation på Serial1
  Serial1.begin(9600); // Erstat med den korrekte baudrate for din enhed
  modbus.begin(2, Serial1); // Angiv slave ID og brug Serial1 porten

  // Definer preTransmission og postTransmission funktioner
  modbus.preTransmission(preTransmission);
  modbus.postTransmission(postTransmission);

  // Start serielle kommunikation til debugging
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  uint8_t result;
  uint16_t windDirectionData[1]; // Array til at opbevare læste data

  // Læs vindretningen fra Modbus enheden
  result = modbus.readHoldingRegisters(0x0000, 1);

  if (result == modbus.ku8MBSuccess) {
    // Gem data fra responsbufferen
    windDirectionData[0] = modbus.getResponseBuffer(0);

    // Konverter data fra registret til en læsbar format
    int windDirection = windDirectionData[0];
    Serial.print("Vindretning (rå værdi): ");
    Serial.print(windDirection);
    Serial.print(". Dette svarer til ");

    // Fortolkning af vindretningen
    switch(windDirection) {
      case 0: Serial.print("Nord"); break;
      case 1: Serial.print("Nordøst-ved-Nord"); break;
      case 2: Serial.print("Nordøst"); break;
      case 3: Serial.print("Nordøst-ved-Øst"); break;
      case 4: Serial.print("Øst"); break;
      case 5: Serial.print("Sydøst-ved-Øst"); break;
      case 6: Serial.print("Sydøst"); break;
      case 7: Serial.print("Sydøst-ved-Syd"); break;
      case 8: Serial.print("Syd"); break;
      case 9: Serial.print("Sydvest-ved-Syd"); break;
      case 10: Serial.print("Sydvest"); break;
      case 11: Serial.print("Sydvest-ved-Vest"); break;
      case 12: Serial.print("Vest"); break;
      case 13: Serial.print("Nordvest-ved-Vest"); break;
      case 14: Serial.print("Nordvest"); break;
      case 15: Serial.print("Nordvest-ved-Nord"); break;
      default: Serial.print("Ukendt retning"); break;
    }
    Serial.println(".");
  } else {
    Serial.print("Fejl ved læsning af Modbus data: ");
    Serial.println(result);
  }

  delay(1000); // Vent 1 sekund før næste læsning
}
```

Comment: RS485 communication is hard to debug if you deal with a lot of "unknowns".
Did you read the sensor successfully before? (e.g. connected to a laptop through a USB to RS485 converter).  
Which device or software is telling you "Fail 226" ? And is there documentation with this device to troubleshoot this error?

Comment: I have never got anything else than "Fail 226" in the Serialmonitor. Nothing is telling us about it in the documentation.

Comment: Then you should share your code, or at least tell us which library you are using to communicate with the sensor.

Comment: I have added the code in the post

Answer (score 0):

Most of your code and configuration seems correct, as far as I can tell.
Still, you encountered the 226 (0xE2) error, the meaning of this error is: slave response timeout.

Generally speaking, there are two possibilities for the source of the issue:

1. wiring is wrong: change the A and B line and try again. Modbus RTU over RS-485 lines is famous for A-B wiring errors (and it is a historical thing).
2. The second possibility is somewhat bad news: many users have reported the same issue with this library: https://github.com/4-20ma/ModbusMaster/issues/93#issuecomment-357524040.
   It seems like the controller switches too early from sending mode to receiving mode, causing the last byte to never reach the wires. Using a digital oscilloscope or logic analyser or something like that would help you to see the actual data on the wires.
   The easiest solution for this problem is: try using a different library?

Comment: We have already tried swapping A and B.
Can you recommend another library?

Comment: Not really for your platform, but I'd suggest using the example from the Controllino website: https://www.controllino.com/rs485-modbusrtu/

Comment: These are only excamples with controillino to controllino and i need to have the controllino as Master and my wind direction transmitter as slave. But how do i write it in the code? :-O

Comment: Found this:
https://wiki.dfrobot.com/SKU_SEN0482_RS485_Wind_Direction_Transmitter_V2

Do you think this code could work with Controllino MAXI?

Comment: I think it "could" work, but the developer of that library for sure did not have a Controllino in mind... So someone with knowledge must evaluate/test it.
Why don't you take the official Controllino example and modify it according to your specific Modbus slave device (the sensor)? That way you have some guarantee that it will work, + support from Controllino I presume and in the process you'll learn a lot of valuable things about Modbus RTU.  
Understanding both the system and the code will be invaluable in the long run.

Comment: I dont get how to use the excamples on Controllino's website, when it is Controllino to Controllino and not Controllino to a sensor. I am pretty new to this kind of stuff.

Comment: This is for a school project and we dont have all time in the world to get the data from the sensor so we should evaluate if we are gonna find another way solution.